# Trying to load rails server in different port; but having issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using rails version 5.1.4. I have following code in my boot.rb file

```
ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] ||= File.expand_path('../Gemfile', __dir__)

require 'bundler/setup' # Set up gems listed in the Gemfile.

require 'rails/commands/server'
module DefaultOptions
  def default_options
    super.merge!(Port: 3020)
  end
end

Rails::Server.send(:prepend, DefaultOptions)
```

But `rails s` resulting me following error

> `require': cannot load such file -- rails/commands/server (LoadError)

Comment: Try chaning `require 'rails/commands/server'` to
`require 'rails/command'` and `require 'rails/commands/server/server_command'`

Answer (score 1):

What should do this code?

```
require 'rails/commands/server'
module DefaultOptions
  def default_options
    super.merge!(Port: 3020)
  end
end

Rails::Server.send(:prepend, DefaultOptions)
```

Actually virgin *config/boot.rb* looks like this:

```
ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] ||= File.expand_path('../Gemfile', __dir__)                                                       

require 'bundler/setup' # Set up gems listed in the Gemfile.
```

To run Rails server on different port you should run it via:

```
bundle exec rails server -p 3020
```

**Updated:**

To change the default port you can use *config/puma.rb*. It has the same line:

```
port        ENV.fetch('PORT') { 3000 }
```

Just change it.

Comment: Yes i have updated my boot.rb code later. What i dont want to do is hit **rails s -p <port_number>** everytime but want to make things work with only **rails s**

Comment: If what i m doing doesnot make sense then please supply the working code that i place in boot.rb

Comment: Return config/boot.rb to initial state and change the port in config/puma.rb

Comment: Thanks . But is it possible to automatically assign a port while running server without specifying any in puma.rb or boot.rb. Like if 3000 is occupied with any application then server runs in 3001 or else?

Comment: It sounds weird. What will you do if 3001 port is busy? And if 3002 as well? How long will you guess a port?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone actually runs into this and wants a solution without using Puma.

I was poking around inside railties-5.2.5/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb
And found a constant that could be changed.

This code worked for me in rails 5.2.8.1

```
require 'rails/command'
require 'rails/commands/server/server_command'

const = 'DEFAULT_PORT'
Rails::Command::ServerCommand.send(:remove_const, const) if Rails::Command::ServerCommand.const_defined?(const)
Rails::Command::ServerCommand.const_set(const, 3020)
```